# how to get the socket type?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, udp

i've a class, that expects to get either an udp or tcp socket.

Now, i want to check, what kind of socket has been given to the class.

```
class NetClientWriter {
    public __construct($socket=null) {
    // do we have a socket?
    if(!is_null($socket)) {
        if(!is_resource($socket) ||
           strtolower(get_resource_type($socket))!='socket') 
            throw new InvalidSocketTypeExeption("This is not a resource of type socket.");
    }
    // socket type
    if(socket_get_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE)==SOCK_STREAM) {
        echo("TCP!!!!!");
    }
    elseif(socket_get_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE)==SOCK_DGRAM) {
        echo("UDP!!!!!");
    }
    else throw new InvalidSocketTypeExeption("Invalid socket type. Just UDP and TCP sockets supported.");
    }
}
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [socket_get_option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-option.php) and check for `SOCK_STREAM` (TCP) vs `SOCK_DGRAM` (UDP).

Comment: another question: how can i see if the tcp socket is already connected?

Comment: Not sure about that; maybe get this information by a read attempt?